# Why does not the extern variable use GOT in dynamic linking?

Tags: c, elf, dynamic-linking

I have below two pieces of code, and I compiled the file sum.c as a dynamic lib (.so), and then compiled it together with main.c. And the command lines I used are listed below:

```
gcc sum.c -shared -fPIC -o libsum.so
gcc -o main main.c -lsum -L.
```

The code:

```
// main.c
#define LEN 2
extern int sharedArr[LEN];
extern int sum(int *arr, int n);
int* array = sharedArr;
int main(void) {
  int val = sum(array, LEN);
  return val;
}

// sum.c
#define LEN 2
int sharedArr[LEN] = { 1, 2 };
int sum(int *arr, int n) {
  int i, s = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    s += arr[i];
  }
  return s;
}
```

And I tried to see the relocation strategy of the variable "sharedArr", but it showed as R_X86_64_64 which was not the way of leveraging GOT but instead a direct access to the .data section, why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why the variable `array` in the `main.c` code? Why not pass `sharedArr` directly to the `sum` function?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The code here is just for demonstrating a specific case. Not a practical case.

Comment: My first guess would be that it is because you did not compile `main.c`, wherein the object in question is defined, to position-independent object code (`-fpic` or `-fPIC`), and neither did you build a position-independent executable (`-fpie` or `-fPIE`).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have tried first compiled the main.c to main.o by "gcc -c main.c -fPIC -o main.o" and then compiled it together with libsum.so, but no luck. Also tried "gcc -o main main.c -lsum -L. -fPIE", and same result.

Comment: @JasonYu I can recommend reading [this](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/05/06/how-c-array-sizes-become-part-of-the-binary-interface-of-a-library) to understand what happens here (variables use _copy relocations_).